# when (position)

Tags: kotlin, navigation-drawer, position

Estoy intentando abrir fragments o activities desde un navigation drawer segun su posicion pero me falta un parametro que no me aclaro muy bien. Tengo un arraylist.

class MainActivityInteractor

```
private fun createNavItemList(): ArrayList<NavItemModel> {

        val navItems:ArrayList<NavItemModel>? = ArrayList()
        navItems?.add(NavItemModel(R.drawable.ic_campo, "Campos"))
        navItems?.add(NavItemModel(R.drawable.ic_work_black_24dp, "Division"))
        return navItems!!
    }
```

esta clase

```
sealed class MainActivityState {
    class ShowNavItems(val navItems: ArrayList<NavItemModel>) : MainActivityState()
    class HandleNavItemClick(val navItem: NavItemModel) : MainActivityState()
}
```

en la linea

```
is ScreenState.Render -> setDrawerItems(screenState.renderState)
```

me falta el parametro positionque no se que poner

en el MainActivity

```
private fun updateDrawerItems(screenState: ScreenState<MainActivityState>?) {
        when (screenState) {
            is ScreenState.Render -> setDrawerItems(screenState.renderState)
        }
    }

    private fun setDrawerItems(renderState: MainActivityState, position: Int) {
        when (renderState) {
            is MainActivityState.ShowNavItems -> {
                navRecycler.apply {
                    layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this@MainActivity, 2)
                    adapter = NavAdapter(renderState.navItems, viewModel::onNavItemClicked)
                }
            }

            is MainActivityState.HandleNavItemClick -> {

                when (position) {
                    0 -> fragmentTransaction(DivFragment())
                    1 -> fragmentTransaction(BuscarFragment())
                }    
                toast("Item Clicked")
                drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
            }
        }
    }
```

y el viewModel:

```
class MainActivityViewModel(private val mainActivityInteractor: MainActivityInteractor) : ViewModel() {

    private lateinit var _navItemsState: MutableLiveData<ScreenState<MainActivityState>>
    val navItemsState: LiveData<ScreenState<MainActivityState>>
        get() {
            if (!::_navItemsState.isInitialized) {
                _navItemsState = MutableLiveData()
                mainActivityInteractor.getNavItems(::onNavItemsLoaded)
            }
            return _navItemsState
        }

    private fun onNavItemsLoaded(navItems: ArrayList<NavItemModel>) {
        _navItemsState.value = ScreenState.Render(MainActivityState.ShowNavItems(navItems))
    }

    fun onNavItemClicked(navItem: NavItemModel) {
        _navItemsState.value = ScreenState.Render(MainActivityState.HandleNavItemClick(navItem))
    }

    class MainActivityViewModelFactory(private val mainActivityInteractor: MainActivityInteractor) :
        ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory() {
        override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
            return MainActivityViewModel(mainActivityInteractor) as T
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

La soloucion es muy simple, pero no me aclaraba if-else

```
is MainActivityState.HandleNavItemClick -> {
                    if (renderState.navItem.name == "Campos"){
                        fragmentTransaction(BuscarFragment())
                    }
```